# How to resize the bitmap image according to mdpi,hdpi and screen size of the mobile

Tags: android

I am using image say 85x85 px (putting this image in drawable-mdpi)

and if i am displaying this image of 85x85 px on [320x480]mdpi screen size device it looks good,
but while displaying this image on [480x800]mdpi device it looks very small.

I wants to know how can i resize this image of (85x85 px) so that it works fine for the device having screen width and height of 480x800, mdpi.

Comment: If you use those images as drawable resources and you determine the view size of them by specifying a percentage of the width and height of the screen, you can just put this image in the `hdpi` folder and the Framework will automatically scale it down for you (this of course depends on the Android version you use and of the implementation you have chosen).

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the image size in the xml in dp. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) post is really helpful.

Comment: Actually i am using these images on canvas, so how can i set the image size in xml, because there is no use of xml file while using canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Consider MDPI image(let say 85x85) as baseline Create images as follow

**FOLDER**  **ImageSize**   **Percentage**

LDPI    **64x64**        75% of baseline

MDPI    **85x85**        100% BASELINE

HDPI    **127x127**      150% of baseline

XHDPI   **170x170**      200% of baseline

Comment: I am doing the same thing what you are saying, creating an image of 64x64 for LDPI,85x85 for MDPI, 127x127 for HDPI,actually i am using these images on canvas and all looks good, but while running my project on emulator using (5.1" WVGA, Screen 5.1", 480x800 large mdpi), the bubbles images looks very small comparing to size of device.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in /drawable, and define the size of the image in your XML as 85dp, it will then be scaled for LDPI/HDPI/XHDPI/XXHDPI and god forbid XXXHDPI.

However, the better solution would to produce HDPI(128px)/XHDPI(170px)/XXHDPI(255px) version of the graphics and put them in /drawable-hdpi, /drawable-xhdpi, /drawable-xxhdpi respectively. This way you can provide the best experience for your users.

---

**[Edit]**

"*dp*" is Android's way of defining *physical* size of an UI objects, so a button of 48x48dp will have roughly the same physical dimension even when run on screen sizes between 240x320 to 1080x1920, for more information check Android developer site's [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

**[Edit 2]**

For images on canvas you can use this to calculate the scaled size of the image:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int newSize = (int)(85 * (dm.densityDpi / 160f));
```

Comment: what does {85*dp*} means ? it makes no sence

Comment: @dineshsharma added reply to my answer

Comment: my concern was with * in 85*dp* it was misleading thing that's it I know what is DP and SP. Now you have made it 85dp problem solved :)

Comment: Yeah I was using the **bold** mark but for some reason it showed up the way it was, so I removed the mark altogether, sorry about the confusion :-/

Comment: Actually I am using images on canvas, and there is no xml file in my project where i can define the size of my images in dp or sp.

Comment: @A.R. Edited my answer. And you should really include the fact that you are using a Canvas in your question, it's very pertinent to the question.

Comment: @KAI, Hey I am sorry about that, I really forgot to mention that i am using my images on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution for this is to produce `LDPI,MDPI,HDPI,XHDPI,XXHDPI` sized images and place it inside the corresponding folders.

Comment: I am doing the same thing what you are saying, creating an image of 64x64 for LDPI,85x85 for MDPI, 127x127 for HDPI,actually i am using these images on canvas and all looks good, but while running my project on emulator using (5.1" WVGA, Screen 5.1", 480x800 large mdpi), the bubbles images looks very small comparing to size of device.

Comment: re-size the image try it up to the limit