# Android xml sp, dp , px issue

Tags: android, html, xml, pixel

I know there is a lot of stuff related to how does android store images. and what does `mhdpi` `xhdmi` `lhdpi` etc means
But my question is a bit different. actually i am working on a screen whose height and weight in `px` is `720*1020 px`. this is not complete HD, this is sort of SD screen. now i designed images for `720*1080 px`  with size equal to `520*370 px` this is the image size. and i have stored the image in `xhdmi`

```
The Issue is
```

When i put the image on screen and give it

```
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
```

the image is displayed on the screen but it shrinks a to half the original size, so i tried giving the height and width equal to `520px` and `370px` respectively to the layout then i get the original size of image

```
My question is:
```

What size should my image contain so that if i wrap content the height and weight, it gets the original size.

Answer (score -1):

In your case the image is resized based on the screen density of the display. Because you placed the image in a higher density folder than your phone is using it will be downscaled. The forth response from [How to resize the bitmap image according to mdpi,hdpi and screen size of the mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082933/how-to-resize-the-bitmap-image-according-to-mdpi-hdpi-and-screen-size-of-the-mob) explains how the images scale depending on screen density.

You can consider the density on your device, the size you expect to be and increase the size with a multiplier so you can save it in xhdpi folder.

Comment: Any reason for the negative vote? I agree the accepted answer has more information but that doesn't make this one incorrect.